# Is Ramona Flowers from Scott Pilgrim vs the World is a symbol?

Tags: comics, scott-pilgrim

Is Ramona Flowers from Scott Pilgrim vs the World a symbol or icon? Is she merely a representation of a 'kind' of girl? Or was she a real person person the story?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an unsupported genre.

Comment: @JohnO  I'd say that Scott Pilgrim vs. the World has a strong Fantasy element.  How else could you describe a movie where a giant animated Yeti fights a giant animated Dragon, and Scott has to fight a flying pirate?

Comment: And since when are comic books not a supported genre? Does that mean we get rid of all the Batman and X-Men questions? This VTC makes no sense to me. Scott and his enemies have powers. If **this** is verboten, all supes should be, too.

Comment: Comic books aren't a genre, they're a medium. Some comic books are westerns, or 1930s noire. Those aren't supported genres. Furthermore, from what I can gather on Wikipedia, these fantasies only exist inside his daydreaming head. That or it's a farce. Neither of these are supported.

Comment: @JohnO Having read the books and watched the movie, there is no real indication that Scott Pilgrim's story is just in his head. It's a fantasy (or whatever superpowers and people turning into coins when vanquished) story which falls under the aegis of this site. Since you have not read the books, you might not be the best person to interpret them and their merits or their genre. (Also, I *meant* "medium" above, but was staring at your first comment when I typed that.)

Comment: I'm familiar enough with the genre to recognize it. It's not a supported genre.

Comment: The characters have superpowers. Hell, even [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0446029/) calls the movie an Action / Comedy / **Fantasy**. (Emphasis mine, obviously.) Fantasy is supported. Maybe you just don't like Scott Pigrim, which is fine, but it's definitely fantasy (or sci-fi) what with its Vegan-Police, pulling swords out of nowhere (and getting sword "power-ups), earning extra lives, having to battle a robot, traveling through subspace doors, etc. Even if it *were* just daydreams, the story is fantastical. Do you VTC any questions about The Wizard of Oz movie, also?

Comment: @JohnO If [Sucker Punch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucker_Punch_(2011_film)) is [recognized as on-topic](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8688/in-snyders-sucker-punch-are-sweet-pea-and-baby-doll-the-same-character), then so is Scott Pilgrim.  All fantasy elements in that movie explicitly took place in their imaginations.

Comment: @Izkata That only shows us another question that should probably be closed. If there's a link on meta though, that might be somewhat authoritative.

Comment: So because many of the scenes may take place in his head, it's supposed to be off topic? So, Inception is out. There are theories that can't be fully refuted that all of Harry Potter and the Pokemon TV show are all in their heads, so those are out. Hell, there's even a theory that all of the Star Wars OT is Luke's fantasy. Guess that's out too. There's nothing to prove that all of Buffy isn't just a fantasy while she's in a psych ward. Gone.

Comment: Related [meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3450/1027)

Comment: @JohnO It's a bit disturbing to see you voting to close a question as off-topic merely because you read a wikipedia entry, and therefore feel you are sufficiently versed in "the genre" to make a blanket statement like this. In point of fact, the comic (and, iirc, the movie as well) make clear distinctions between what is in the dream sequences, and what is outside of the dream sequences. The dream sequences are revealed to only occur because Ramona uses dimensional portals to travel *in "real" life*, and one convenient portal happens to run through Scott's head.

Comment: @Beofett Nothing you've described sounds to me like a supported genre. If it were, then there are effectively no limits on what is allowed, other than the whims of the cliques here on this SE. Are Benny Hill skits on topic? South Park? How about West Wing? Scott Pilgrim isn't a story that describes a universe where the laws of physics and reality are different... the fantastic elements are exaggerations meant to be farcical. It's a story-telling technique, not a genre.

Comment: @JohnO Really, you need to stop going by wikipedia.  Or are you trolling? A world where a girl makes a career as a courier by exploiting dimensional doorways that allow her to teleport from place to place nearly instantaneously doesn't sound like a universe where the laws of physics and reality are different?  Using magic powers to summon fire-breathing demons is just an exaggeration? Seriously?

Comment: You've just described "farce". Not science fiction, and not fantasy. When Benny Hill dies and floats up to heaven with little angel wings and a halo, that's not supernatural/fantasy, it's still *farce*.

Comment: So you're arguing that any soft scifi, or anything that incorporates humor, is off topic, and no different than Benny Hill?  I believe that's the end of any chance of a reasonable discussion.  I'm out.  Don't forget to VTC every *Discworld* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, she represents the [Awesome McCoolname](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AwesomeMcCoolname) [Mysterious Past](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MysteriousPast) [Bi The Way](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BiTheWay) [McNinja](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/McNinja) [ActionGirl](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ActionGirl) that you see in media all the time.